# How to fix this 'Attachment is not a constructor' error with my bot?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

When I made my bot for Discord and tried to attach an image, I can't because of this error

It's a bot for Discord that runs on `Discord.js`
I tried const Attachment on the beginning, but that didn't work, removed new and const in the code didn't work too

```
        case 'about':
            message.channel.send('I am Damabot, developed by Damadion!')
            const attachment = new Attachment('./DidYouThinkIAmTheRealFace.png')
            message.channel.send('I am Damabot, developed by Damadion!' + attachment)
            console.log('Bot successfully replied')
            break;
```

I expected it to send an attachment, but it didn't and sent this error

Comment: hi, have you tried using MessageAttachment instead of Attachment?

Comment: Hi, now it says MessageAttachment is not a constructor

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
message.channel.send('I am Damabot, developed by Damadion!', { files: ['./DidYouThinkIAmTheRealFace.png'] });
```

It adds the file directly into the message, so you don't have to create Attachment. I use this my BOT, and it works just fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you [edit] your answer to add some explanation for the code?

Answer (score 0):

`Attachment` is a class within Discord.js. Unless you're using a destructuring assignment for your require statement (`const { Attachment } = require('discord.js')`), Node.js is trying to construct an Attachment object based on a class within your code. When it finds that there is none, it throws your error.

If you want to stick to constructing Attachment objects, you can use:

```js
const attachment = new Discord.Attachment('./path/to/file.png', 'name'); // name is optional

message.channel.send('Hey there', attachment)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Otherwise, you can use the `files` property of a message like so:

```js
message.channel.send('Hey there', {
  files: ['./path/to/file.png']
})
.catch(console.error);
```

The latter allows you to also send an embed (and maybe use the attachment in your embed).

[*Discord.js Docs*](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome)

Answer (score 0):

For me the following code worked:

```
const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment("url");
channel.send(attachment);
```

`Discord.Attachment` was replaced with `Discord.MessageAttachement`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I ran `npm install` to update my packages and to check if my discord version was outdated and therefore causing any issues.
After that, I decided to go through the docs and found this snippet here:

```js
const attachment=new Discord.MessageAttachment("enter the URL u wanna enter here")
const generalChannel=client.channels.cache.get("enter ur channel id here")
$generalChannel.send(attachment);
```

At least, it has worked for me. Please let me know if it works for you as well.